# Rational tools Purify/Quantify finding pdb files

Tags: pdb-files, purify, quantify

Do the rational tools follow the _NT_SYMBOL_PATH to find .pdb files? It seems from my experience that they are not and that the .pdb files need to be collocated with the .dll's and .exe's I am trying to intrument.

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found some references that indicate that the pdb and dll/exe need to be  collocated.

Verify that the .pdb file for the .exe or .dll is in the [same directory](http://wiki.scilab.org/Purify%207.0%20Recommended%20Settings%20for%20Visual%20Studio%20.NET%20and%20Visual%20Studio%202005) as the corresponding .exe or .dll. The .pdb file contains the Microsoft format symbol information. If you move your .exe or .dll to a working directory, you must also move the corresponding .pdb file.

Verify that the pdb files are present in the [same folder](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21306997) as the application modules so that the modules can be instrumented in precise mode. Precise mode instrumentation is a level of error-checking instrumentation that provides full runtime error detection and precisely pinpoints problems in any component in your program. If the application does not have the correct debug info, PurifyPlus will instrument in minimal mode and data will not be collected for that particular module.